# Which is better? cast nullable type or retrieve the value with Value property?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Is there a performance benefit to one way over the other?

Are there other reasons to choose one over the other?

Comment: can you show the code you're looking at?

Comment: Do you mean casting nullable type to non nullable type (as hunter is doing) or just retrieving the value of a nullable type.

Comment: They call the same code. I believe the Get function casts (or vice versa? It's been a while)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Is there a performance benefit to one way over the other?

No. They both compile to the exact same IL. The cast is syntactic sugar for the Value property. This code:

```
int? x = null;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
Console.WriteLine((int)x);
```

compiles to these IL instructions, ignoring `nop`s: (you can test this yourself using ildasm, ILSpy, DotPeek, etc.)

```
// int? x = null;
ldloca.s 0
initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>

// Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
ldloca.s 0
call instance !!0 [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_Value()
call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

// Console.WriteLine((int)x);
ldloca.s 0
call instance !!0 [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_Value()
call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
```

> Are there other reasons to choose one over the other?

I prefer to avoid casts when I can, because there's always the potential for them to get out of sync with the actual type. If I change my variable from `int?` to `byte?`, then all my casts are wrong -- but if I was using `.Value`, I'm free to change the variable as necessary. To me, the hard cast doesn't add anything in terms of readability, but it does cost in terms of maintainability.

Comment: .Value will also get out of sync if the type is no longer nullable. I prefer casting because then if things change I will know exactly where there could be problems.

Comment: @Telavian If the type is no longer nullable then wouldn't `.Value` also fail to compile? So either way, cast or not you'd have to address some semantic issues.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a performance benefit to one way over the other?

Performance would be negligible

> Are there other reasons to choose one over the other?

Readability?

---

```
// most readable
public int GetValue(int? value)
{
    return value.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

---

```
// less readable
public int GetValue(int? value)
{
    return value ?? default(int);
}
```

---

```
// least readable
public int GetValue(int? value)
{
    return value.HasValue ? value.Value : default(int);
}
```

---

```
//least readable reversed return type/param type
public int? GetValue(int value)
{
    return value == 0 ? null : (int?)value;
}
```

Comment: I'd put GetValueOrDefault() at the top of the readabililty list

Comment: I would like to add my opinion that since type is automatically determined nowadays `return value ?? default;` is most readable.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>(Old question? Who cares. Contemporary problem.)</sub>

First, Joe [provides a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116426/321013), and given the current state of C#, I guess I agree with him:

> ... potential for them to get out of sync with the actual type. If I
>   change my variable from int? to byte?, then all my casts are wrong --
>   but if I was using .Value, I'm free to change the variable as
>   necessary.

The problem is that you *always* are committing to a type, because if you use `.Value` then you are committing to `Nullable<TAny>` and if you're using the cast you're committing to "`ICastableTo<TSpecific>`"<sup>made up name</sup>

That said, Joe's advice is still valid, because the compiler will be much better at catching invalid `.Value` usage than potentially semantically invalid casts that may still compile, and *you want the compiler to catch as much stuff as it can when changing types*.